# For Loop Classic ASP Renameing Result Sets

Tags: loops, for-loop, vbscript, asp-classic, resultset

I am trying to create a new result set each time I run the query... This way when I get to displaying the information, I will have different result sets for my different tables... Is it possible to change the name of a result set in a for loop?

Something like this would explain what I mean.. On the last line I do a For i = 0 to count -2... I am wondering if I could have the rsTemp(1,2,3,4,5) set to I so that if I do have 5 Queries... I would have rsTemp1,rsTemp2,rsTemp3,rsTemp4, and rsTemp5:

```
        '1st Table Informations
    strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT custpart FROM dex_racklabels..rl_master where custpart like '%-%' and userid <> 'dakkota' and status <> 'S'"
    Set rsTemp5 = conPaintDC.Execute(strSQL)
    If Not rsTemp5.EOF Then
        'If this returns something create an array of the returned rack serial numbers
        Do While Not rsTemp5.EOF
            strArrayPart = strArrayPart & "'" & rsTemp5("custpart") & "',"
            rsTemp5.MoveNext
        Loop
        rsTemp5.MoveFirst
    End If

    'Split up the Part Numbers
    ArraySplit = Split(strArrayPart,",")


    'Count how many items you have
    For each item In ArraySplit
        count = count + 1
    Next

    'Run query for each
    For i = 0 to count - 2
        strSQL = "SELECT COUNT(serialnbr) FROM [dex_racklabels].[dbo].[rl_detail] where custpart = " & ArraySplit(i) & ""

        Set rsTemp(1,2,3,4,5) = conPaintDC.Execute(strSQL)
        If Not rsTemp(1,2,3,4,5).EOF Then
            response.write(strSQL)
        End If
    Next
    response.end()
```

Answer (score 0):

"Numbered" variables (e.g. rsTemp1,rsTemp2,...) are a bad idea and should be avoided. In your case - a loop that deals with many recordsets sequentially - there is no need for extra/special/fancy variables at all, re-using a local variable is enough:

```
For Each query_spec
    Set oRS = Obtain rs from query_spec
    display oRS
    close oRS
Next
```

If you need more than one recordset at the same time, use a collection (Array, Dictionary):

```
init collection c()
For Each query_spec
    Set c(query_spec) = Obtain rs from query_spec
Next
For i = 1 To UBound(c) Step 2
    WorkWith2Rs c(i-1), c(i)
Next
```